# Наследование в EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

Допустим, были сгенерированы Классы-сущности и мне захотелось расширить какую-то сущность дополнительными полями(Например, вспомогательными для расчетов), которые не хочу что бы мапились.

Я выполняю наследование от сущности, создаю экземпляр, который заполняю данными.

Затем я хочу добавить запись в базу в таблицу Entity и выполняю `db.Entity.Add((Entity)ExtendedEntity)` и получаю ошибку

> 'Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity'

Подскажите, как избежать ошибки или может быть есть более корректный путь?

Comment: Как настроено отображение?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а где посмотреть? Я генерил классы на основании DataBase First и настройки никакие не менял.

Comment: Если вы генерили классы по базе - откуда у вас вообще могло взяться наследование?..

Comment: Любой класс сущности EF должен иметь отображение на базу, дочерний - не исключение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Т.е получается, если я хочу из дочернего класса добавить элемент в базовую сущность, то операции приведения не достаточно? Необходимо явно создавать базовый объект и в него переносить значения?

Comment: Операция приведения не нужна. Но должно быть настроено отображение на базу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, подскажите, а где и как его настроить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - вы понимаете разницу между `DB First` и `Code First`, это очень разные подходы. Если их мешать получиться лапша.

Comment: @Mirdin насколько я понял, у него **уже** лапша :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не у него первичный период обучения `EF` - главное придерживаться одного подхода и все получиться.

Answer (score 1):

Если передаете экземпляр этого нового типа в EF, то ожидаете, что он будет сохраняться (а иначе зачем суете в EF?). А раз так, то о нем нужно знать EF и о том как его маппить. Для того чтобы подцепил потомка добавляете его сразу, базовый класс схватить и так. О типах мапинга наследников на https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2. Затем ваши поля для расчетов помечаете как `[NotMapped]`. Об этом на https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#NotMapped

Удачи!